# Side banner on a webpage

Tags: html, css

How would I make it so the banners along the top and bottom of this page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ge5.jpg) are instead at both sides of the page?

I currently have them both fixed to the top and bottom of the page:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
    z-index: 999;
}

#footer { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <a href="project.html">
        <div id="header">
            <button id="next-button" href="project.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-4x"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </a>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="splash">
            <div id="name">
                <h1 class="wow animated flipInX">Max Wilson</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="profile">
                <img src="img/Logo.png" class="wow animated rollIn" data-wow-delay="1s">
            </div>

            <div id="subtext">
                <h2 class="wow animated fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="2s">Aspiring Developer </h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<a href="project.html">
    <div id="footer">
        <button id="prev-button" href="project.html"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-4x"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried floating the header and footer to the left?

For example:

```
#header { 
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50px; 
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #44f;
}

#footer { 
    position: relative;
    float: left; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #44f;
}

#wrapper{   text-align: center; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}

#main{ width: 800px;
    float:left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you! Do you also have a way to center the arrow on the sides?

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to center, the main content or the text at the side: http://i.imgur.com/NFPU6Nr.jpg

Comment: OH, vertically algined-- try this: `.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}`
Credit to: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and interesting method: giving the `body` `display: flex` and the content `flex-grow: 1` so it occupies all the available space and pins the other elements to either side.

```
<div class="side">
  <h3>asdf</h3>
  <h3>asdf</h3>
  <h3>asdf</h3>
  <h3>asdf</h3>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>asdfasdf</p>
</div>

<div class="side">
  <h3>asdf</h3>
  <h3>asdf</h3>
  <h3>asdf</h3>
  <h3>asdf</h3>
</div>
```

```
body {
  display: flex;
}

.side, #content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.side {
  background: blue;
}

#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: grey;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JackHasaKeyboard/rz86xwxh/2/